# TypeScript + AngularJSでのng-file-uploadモジュールの使用方法

Tags: angularjs, typescript

TypeScriptとAngularJS + ng-file-uploadモジュールを使った開発の質問です。

現在、以下のリポジトリで開発を行っています。
http://github.com/aiya000/EndrollMate.git

こちらの動作確認は以下の手順で行えます。

1. $ git clone http://github.com/aiya000/EndrollMate.git && cd EndrollMate
2. $ ./build.sh
3. index.htmlを開く

---

現在起こっている問題として、index.html中の


`<input type="file" name="backgroundImage" accept="image/*" ng-file-upload="bgCtrl.fileSelect($files)"/>`


の
`ng-file-upload="bgCtrl.fileSelect($files)"`で
ts/index.tsにある`BackgroundImageController#fileSelect(FileList)`
の呼び出しを行おうとしています。

しかしindex.htmlをブラウザで開いた上で適当なファイルを選択しても反応がない…といった感じです。
FireFoxでの開発ツールでも読み込みエラーは見られていません。

---

どうか、TypeScript + AngularJSに知見のある方、解決方法
またはこのような場合のうまいデバッグ方法などありましたら教えてくださると幸いです。

以下に当環境を記します。

Ubutu 15.04
Firefox 40.0
tsc 1.5.3

Comment: うまいデバッグ方法、というほどのものでもないですが、カスタムディレクティブが動かない時はそのディレクティブの定義箇所を探してそれが呼ばれているかどうかを`alert()`で確認してみたりします。今回はその過程で`ng-file-select`というディレクティブが存在しないことがわかりました。

Comment: ngf-select="alert('foo')"…みたいな感じでしょうか？

Comment: ディレクティブの**定義**箇所です。`ng-file-upload.js`の`ngFileUpload.directive('ngfSelect', ...)`内で`alert()`してみる、とかですね。

Comment: !! 大元の方にalert()を入れてみるんですね、確かにそれならば呼ばれれば絶対にわかりますね…。 ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイルの選択を検知するためのディレクティブは`ng-file-select`ではなく`ngf-select`ですね。それから、`index.ts`の

```
let appEndrollMate = angular.module("appEndrollMate", []);
```

の部分は

```
let appEndrollMate = angular.module("appEndrollMate", ["ngFileUpload"]);
```

として、ng-file-uploadモジュールを読み込む必要があると思います。